# Make a Sub-class run inside a public main class

Tags: java, class

So i’m new to Java and i’ve learnt a couple of things and decided to try on different projects, i saw this online and tried it but it only runs the main class but i also want it to display the menu part too which is in a different class , Without the menu the rest of the class isn’t going to work

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BankApplication {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your 'Name' and 'CustomerId' to access your Bank account:");
        String name=sc.nextLine();
        String customerId=sc.nextLine();
        BankAccount obj1=new BankAccount(name,customerId);
        obj1.menu();
    }
}

class BankAccount{
    double bal;
    double prevTrans;
    String customerName;
    String customerId;

    BankAccount(String customerName,String customerId){
        this.customerName=customerName;
        this.customerId=customerId;
    }


    void deposit(double amount){
        if(amount!=0){
            bal+=amount;
            prevTrans=amount;
        }
    }

    void withdraw(double amt){
        if(amt!=0 && bal>=amt){
            bal-=amt;
            prevTrans=-amt;
        }
        else if(bal<amt){
            System.out.println("Bank balance insufficient");
        }
    }

    void getPreviousTrans(){
        if(prevTrans>0){
            System.out.println("Deposited: "+prevTrans);
        }
        else if(prevTrans<0){
            System.out.println("Withdrawn: "+Math.abs(prevTrans));
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("No transaction occured");
        }
    }

    void menu(){
        char option;
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome "+customerName);
        System.out.println("Your ID:"+customerId);
        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.println("a) Check Balance");

I wanted the code to run the menu there too so i could test the functions included, please is there a way to make it run or call the second class?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works on my machine. But I guess your problem is the app getting shut down imidiatelly after receiving the welcome message and "a) check balance".

This is happening because after the `System.out.println("a) Check Balance);` you're not actually accessing the Scanner. Add a `String option = sc.nextLine();` to your code.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your contribution but my problem isn’t the code not good enough to work, it’s just everytime i run it on Vscode IDE i expect it to print the menu options after i input my name and account number. Please is there a way i have to make the class call up immediately or do i have to call the class myself since it’s not a main

Comment: What exactly do you mean by class call up? When I used IntelliJ to execute your code, everything except the thing I've mentioned in the answered worked as expected. Could you further elaborate on what exactly is wrong? And a little tip: This information would've been very useful in the original question - Always mention such things.

Comment: oh i just realized i wrote the correct code here but omitted    BankAccount obj1=new BankAccount(name,customerId);
        obj1.menu();
    from my code. I just imputed it but the response i got is “no enclosing instance of type BankApplication is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type BankApplication(e.g x.new A() where x is an instance of BankApplication” how can i fix that please?

Comment: So everything works now? What exactly was the mistake? if my answer didn't help, could you write your own answer and mark it as a solution, so that other people who might have the same problem, know what was wrong?

Comment: my mistake was omitting calling the menu(), i already edited my response to you to make it more elaborate, so i did all that now and i’m getting this error response “no enclosing instance of type BankApplication is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type BankApplication(e.g x.new A() where x is an instance of BankApplication”. Is there something i’m doing wrong there?

Comment: The error occurs where exactly? Cuz for me the entire app works perfectly fine